# intersectsLine() function is not working as expected

Tags: java, shapes, intersection, rectangles

[image]I am trying to check if a line intersects a set of rectangles.

This is my code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rectangle2D.Double rectangle1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(32, 64, 32, 32);     
        Rectangle2D.Double rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 32, 32, 32);      

        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(36, 63, 5, 12);

        System.out.println(rectangle1.intersectsLine(line)); // outputs false. Why?
        System.out.println(rectangle2.intersectsLine(line)); // outputs true as expected
    }
}
```

As you can see, the start point (36, 63) is within `rectangle1`, but apparently this line segment doesn't intersect the rectangle that it starts in.

However, it intersects the rectangle that stores the end point (5, 12).

Any idea why?

How do I get it to detect intersection?

Comment: The line doesn't intersect the first rectangle, that's why Java is giving you the correct answer. Perhaps you're confused on how the Rectangle2D.Double constructor works?

Comment: Is it the constructor or the `intersectsLine` function? Either way, how can I check if a Rectangle contains a particular line segment?

Comment: It's the constructor of course. The intersects method is working appropriately.

Comment: Again your assumptions about the Rectangle2D.Double constructor are wrong. The first two parameters are the start ponit, and the last two are the width and height.  But don't take my word for it, **draw it**.

Comment: I understand that's how the constructors work and I took that into consideration. So shouldn't rectangle1 be northwest of rectangle2? And shouldn't point (36, 63) be within rectangle1?

Comment: The first two arguments to the constructor are the coordinates of the rectangle's UPPER LEFT corner.

Comment: Correct. And the width goes to the right and the height goes *down*

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so how is rectangle2 (0,  32) higher than rectangle1 (32, 64) when (32, 64) is higher than (0, 32)?

Comment: For Java, the y direction is **down**.

Comment: But that shouldn't matter in this, since intersection will not matter which way Java draws the y direction, since the line end points and the rectangles will change in a covariant fashion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ahh ok I see. Now I'm not used to thinking like that  and I want to draw rectangles where the origin (0,0) is on the bottom left, Y increases up and X to the right. Is there any way to draw rectangles with that orientation?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am drawing a graph with regions where the origin (0,0) is the on bottom left, X goes to the right, and Y up

Comment: Again, it shouldn't matter since intersection is invariant under a reflection transformation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does matter. Imagine a graph with (0, 0) at the bottom left and Y increasing upwards (and X increasing to the right). A line with a start point at (36, 63) will have that start point be contained within the rectangle whose upper left corner is at (32, 64) and whose width and height are 32. Draw it out on paper and you'll see.

Comment: But 1) if you flip the y coordinates, both the line and the rectangle flip. 2) if you study the science of affine transformations -- which is what a y coordinate system flip is -- you'll know that intersections remain invariant.

Comment: Ok I see. Looks like I'll need to do some re-thinking. At least now I know what the "problem" is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line does not intersect rectangle1, and that's why Java is giving you back the correct answer. Draw the lines in a GUI and see for yourself. Perhaps you're confused on the Rectangle2D.Double constructor -- the last parameters are width and height.

Draw the GUI and see; they almost touch, but not quite:

[image]

Drawing **both** rectangles:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 850;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    Rectangle2D rectangle1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(32, 64, 32, 32);     
    // Rectangle2D rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 32, 32, 32);      

    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(36, 63, 5, 12);

    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        double scale = 8.0;
        g2.scale(scale, scale); // make it big to show it for you
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.draw(rectangle1);
        // g2.draw(rectangle2);
        g2.draw(line);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Test mainPanel = new Test();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite interesting, when I draw rectangle2 as well as rectangle1, the overall picture doesn't look like what I linked in my question above.